# Window resolution handling without javascript

Tags: html, css

Is there any CSS property to deal window resolution. I created a HTML page taking total resolution width as 1424px.When I open it on different resolution I see a scroll bar & resolution of HTML does not adjust automatically. I don't want the scrollbar to be seen in maximized size of the page. Is it possible without using javascript.At the same time how to increase the resolution when itself is created in lower res.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best you're going to get with CSS is @media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 799px) {
  /* styles for smaller screen */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 800px) {
  /* styles for larger screen */
}
```

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for.